# geometric distribution expected value proof doubts

Tags: probability, distributions, geometric-distribution

[image]

Hello,I have problems understanding the proof for the expected value of geometric distributions.

I don't know why the bound upper is set to infinity? For binomial distributions, the upper bound of sigma is n, a finite value...what has changed??? Why put infinity instead for geometric?

I also didn't understand whether we are treating p as a constant (taking it out of sigma) or as a variable (differentiating sth with respect to p).

Answer (score 0):

Geometric distribution arises from the scenario where we consider the number of failures (trials, in OP's case) before the first successful trial, with probability $p.$ The number of failures (trials) before the occurrence of first success can be any non-negative integer, that is, $k\in\mathbb Z_+$ ($k\in\mathbb N$).Thus the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of geometric distribution is $\mathbb Z_+.$ Here $p$ is the parameter. The number of trials is not fixed, unlike in case of binomial distribution, where we seek to find the probability of number of successes in $n$ independent Bernoulli trials, with success probability $p.$ Here $(n, p) $ is the parameter.

In the derivation,  the summation is on $k$ and hence $p$ can be taken out of the expectation calculation.  For the sake of manipulation, we introduce differentiation for easing the calculations -- the step is valid as the series is uniformly convergent.